# Does anyone have a tutorial or some guide to get started with Rosetta protein modeling and design tool? (I am a Mac user)

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, bioinformatics, protein-folding

I have been trying to get started with Rosetta protein modeling and design software bundle. I searched online but the tutorials in the Rosetta website are difficult follow. I have the binaries already downloaded.

I would highly appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

My initial goal is to model a few proteins structures and to design basic backbone structures.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is really the place for this kind if question. You might be better off going to   biostars or reddit bioinformatics if you have a specific question. Good luck.

Comment: You give no link to the software you are enquiring about, so we cannot check what sort of support they provide, but you should certainly check yourself. If there is no such support, I suggest SE Bioinformatics would be a better bet.

Comment: Welcome to Bio stackexchange! I edited your question to make it more specific, and detailed. I found through a youtube search that meiler lab has some nice tutorials for rosetta, like this video on [protein design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w67qOgGLBbA)

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to like my answer.

Rosetta is not intended to be accessible to the general public. the complexity of the codebase and of the biophysics means that it is typically learned through mentorship and academic training.

If you are really interested in pursuing it, check the faculty list on the [Rosetta Commons](https://www.rosettacommons.org/) website, and start emailing professors asking to volunteer as an early career scientist.

You will have so. many. questions. at every step. it's just... you'll be so much more successful if you have mentors to guide you.

You may be interested in [foldit](https://fold.it/) standalone. It's the more options version of foldit. With foldit, you can work on real biological problems in a training setting. You might be annoyed by this because you want to program, but getting intuition for the structural biophysics is step 1. foldit was explicitly designed as a training tool for people (like you) who do not know about rosetta. Using foldit will teach you about the score function, for example.

Everyone starts with foldit. I started with foldit.

Getting good at foldit will increase your chances of a Rosetta professor agreeing to mentor you.

If you are an undergrad, there is a Rosetta Commons mentorship program about to become active - please join the Rosetta Commons forum and inquire there for info.

If you're being asked to do this for some school thing, it's absolutely ridiculous for someone to think you could do it without at least several class days about it.

In summary - I strongly encourage you to reach out to the Rosetta Commons faculty and mentorship program if you would like to seriously pursue Rosetta.